# How to feed a Model with a DOM tree

Tags: jena

The XML data to be used with the Model is available as an org.w3c.dom.Element, due to unmarshalling an XML wrapper containing up to 100 individual rdf:RDF nodes.

Currently I'm converting the DOM tree to a string, and an InputStream fed with the String can be passed to the Model read method.

Isn't there a more direct method for feeding a Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is class `DOM2Model.create(...).load(...)` which might work - very old code.

The main RDF/XML parsing is SAX-based and streaming, not XML-tree based.

Comment: Thank you - works fine. I see no reason to do an extra XML-to-String transformation just to permit SAX-based parsing.

Comment: Goog to know DOM2Model works. It's of the beaten path for application usage. The (far) more common case is reading from file or network where the input is bytes.